# How can we call antlr4 TestRig with MultiChannel?

Tags: antlr4

### Testing a grammar with ANTLR4 grun is not working when using MultiChannelBaseParser

We have separated grammar Lexer and Parser in ANTLR4: ModelLexer.g4 and ModelParser.g4. The start rule is model. The parser use multichannel.

In ModelParser.g4

```
parser grammar ModelParser;

options {
  superClass=MultiChannelBaseParser;
  tokenVocab = ModelLexer;
}
```

In ModelLexer.g4

```
channels{
    GRAMMARPART
}

NewLine: [\n\r]+ -> channel(GRAMMARPART);

...
```

This is because in some parts of the grammar we need to ignore NewLines but in a particular part of the grammar we need to recognize NewLine as part of the grammar rules.

In ModelParser.g4

```
model: {disable(ModelLexer.GRAMMARPART);} otherrules;
...
somerule: {enable(ModelLexer.GRAMMARPART);} rules {disable(ModelLexer.GRAMMARPART);};
...
```

in `rules`, `NewLine` is part of the grammar.

The parser is working correctly when packed with `mvn install`, a .jar is produced and the parser is invoked from a program with the correct results.

But, when testing the grammar using `grun` (as an alias for `java -Xmx500M org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig`) ( with or without -Xmx option or different memory size) the parser is not working correctly becase the channel is not being activated.

Compiling with maven we have the generated `target/classes` and inside we have `mypackage` containing the parser `.class`'s

`...target/classes$ grun mypackage.Model model -tokens -gui testFile > tokens-output.txt`

The content of .../target/classes is

- mypackage

  - ModelLexer.class
  - ModelParser$*.class (representing several .class with this prefix)
  - ModelParser.class
  - ModelParserBaseVisitor.class
  - ModelParserVisitor.class
  - MultiChannelBaseParser.class
  - MultiChannelTokenStream.class
  - MyErrorListener.class
  - visitors (directory)

The parser is not working properly from TestRig. The result is

line 48:0 missing NewLine at .....

line 49:0 missing NewLine at  .....

line 122:0 extraneous input '<EOF>' expecting {NewLine,   .....

How can we set grun (TestRig) that MultiChannelBaseParser should be used?

I haven't got a short example. Our system is running as a Sonarqube plugin for Vensim and it is working with multichannel. The problem is when running TestRig.

The code and maven based build instruction are available here:
https://github.com/locomotionH2020/VensimPlugin4SonarQube

Here a quite simple .mdl file for testing the parser https://github.com/locomotionH2020/VensimPlugin4SonarQube/blob/master/src/test/resources/smooth_ok.mdl

Comment: Cam you edit your question to include enough Java code and grammar for a working example so that others can reproduce that what you describe?

Comment: Indeed, there is no `disable()` or `enable()` in the [Parser API](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Parser.html) or any of the superclasses. We need to see what you are doing in your base class for the parser. I, too, have to treat newlines as you describe, but it is not possible to simply swap a channel like that on the standard token stream.

Comment: I have edited the question to add the urls for the system repo and a simple file for testing the parser.

Answer (score 0):

The `grun` alias `java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig` doesn't know that it needs to create an instance of `MultiChannelTokenStream` for the token stream that  `ModelParser` expects.  It just [creates a `CommonTokenStream`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TestRig.java#:%7E:text=CommonTokenStream%20tokens%20%3D%20new%20CommonTokenStream(lexer)%3B) and passes it to your parser.

Since the `MultiChannelBaseParse` uses the following code to implement `enable` and `disable`:

```java
    public void enable(int channel) {
        if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
            ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).enable(channel);
        }
    }

    public void disable(int channel) {
        if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
            ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).disable(channel);
        }
    }
```

those methods are effectively NO-Ops when used with `grun`.

If I replace that code with:

```java
    public void enable(int channel) {
        // if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
        ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).enable(channel);
        // }
    }

    public void disable(int channel) {
        // if (_input instanceof MultiChannelTokenStream) {
        ((MultiChannelTokenStream) _input).disable(channel);
        // }
    }
```

Then `grun` blows up with `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream cannot be cast to class MultiChannelTokenStream (org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream and MultiChannelTokenStream are in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Is there a strong reason for not tu allow creation of different token stream? Can we contribute to a TestRig? It could be with a new command line parameter to set the name of the token stream class (default value runtime.CommonTokenStream) and a factoryMethod call instead of the direct new in current line 172 https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/d2e25842dfa1a7daadfce6fdf2197df5f2b7589e/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TestRig.java#L172

Comment: ANTLR is open source, so you could submit a PR.  You’d probably want to start a discussion about this before doing the work.  I suspect that TestRig (grun) already has enoug options that there might be resistance to adding another, but I could be wrong.  It’s not at all uncommon for grammars to reach a point of customization that TestRig just doesn’t work for them (usually it’s target-specific grammars), so I find myself using TestRig as I’m starting a grammar but move on once I have code written to actually use the grammar.   Since you have working code, what is your use case for TestRig?

Comment: We have a project that has been running for 3 years and has begun to fail sometimes. The solution has many layers above the parser. It is invoked from the sonar-scanner and a plugin deployed on a Sonarqube instance. The log analysis suggests a relation with the parser. We built an unofficial grammar of an uncommon language under Vensim. The size of the Vensim code we are analyzing has grown a lot, the version of the Vensim IDE has been changed, and the possibility of a syntactic structure that our grammar does not support arises.

Comment: We would like to test with TestRig the file that is causing problems, in order to isolate the error from the rest of the layers.

Comment: I doubt it will get much priority as a core enhancement . It’s an exceptional use case and fairly trivial to write your own “TestRig” small program that uses your TokenStream instead of the default.  It would just be a few lines of Java.